Setting body text color to a "less harsh" white, only if `prefers-color-scheme:dark` AND `html { color-scheme:light dark; }` as part of normalize.css?
As part of a normalize.css type thing, I'd like to set the default body text color to a less harsh white in dark mode, like this:
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    color: #e1e1e1; /* less harsh white */
  }
}

The problem is that if the document doesn't have this:
html {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}

Then the page's background will still be white, but my color:#e1e1e1; rule will still be activated, resulting in white-ish text on a white background.
Important note: I don't control what code the dev writes on the page. Think of this like a normalize.css for a JSBin/CodePen type platform. I.e. this normalize.css must work correctly regardless of whatever code that the dev has written. Please see the comments for some extra clarification on this point.
Is there a way to only "activate" my color:#e1e1e1; rule if the user has prefers-color-scheme: dark and the html has color-scheme:light dark;?

Would adding html { color-scheme: dark; } inside your media query not work?

@somethinghere Unfortunately not, since that would force the page into dark mode (e.g. it makes the background of the page black) when the user's device is in dark mode, even though the dev didn't necessarily specify that. The goal of this normalize.css is to not have impact the page styles in any way other than a few changes like fixing the default text color in dark mode to be a little less harsh on the eyes. It shouldn't do something as significant as forcing the color scheme of the page.

To be honest, I support dark mode by simply enforcing light mode and making changes using dark mode detection. If you just use html { color-scheme: light; } by default no auto changes will be applied and you can take it from there. But you will have to force it somehow or you won't be able to escape those dreaded default dark mode bahviours. Also, you are not "forcing" a color scheme. It's a... suggestion, if anything.

@somethinghere A key requirement here is that literally nothing else is changed by this normalize.css, other than a few specific "superficial"/minor things, like the default dark mode text color. By adding html { color-scheme: light; }, it will activate the color: #e1e1e1; rule if the user's device is set to dark mode, even though the page may not support dark mode. And that means my normalize.css will cause the text color to be #e1e1e1 even though the background is white. Like I said, this is for a JSBin style sandbox, so I can't non-trivially "mess with" web-standard behavior.

So, other than this minor normalization stuff, regular HTML+CSS written in this sandbox should work the same as if they just wrote an index.html and loaded it in their browser, locally.

I guess you're in a bind then, as being able to use features requires you... actually need to be able to address those features.
